# How to flush coolant with only access to expansion tank?

Tags: coolant, opel, corsa, flush

OPEL CORSA B Sedan 1.6 IE 1999.

I would like to flush the coolant and bleed my brakes.

For the coolant, I have bought German HEPU antifreeze, Anyways, I only have a reservoir bottle and I do not have a radiator cap.I have a garden hose and a funnel and a drain pan.

**How do you flush the coolant with only access to the expansion tank?** Do you just stick the hose pipe with medium pressure in to the reservoir bottle, after it starts circulating (if it actually does) I can start the car and watch the temperature, then turn on the heater and the fan on 4 for a while, and continue the hose pipe flush. I would reckon a whole 10-15 minutes of this procedure.
**

Can i use the German HEPU (96 % percent antifreeze) coolant alone and with no water - so i.e can you in general use antifreeze alone with no water?

We get like -10 maybe worst case and up to +35 degrees Centigrade.

**Does my flush procedure sound correct?**

**Is it okay to use antifreeze alone?**

Comment: Hello anybody home?

Comment: Imre - I'd suggest keeping your question about procedure, but removing the "Can I use X" bit - you could ask it as a separate question (although we may already have that one on the site - will try and find it)

Answer (score 3):

*I completely forgot about the draining part, but have no time left. So, here about he antifreeze part. May be, I'll write more later*

---

It may work, but is not recommended.

### Freezing point

Antifreeze freezes at -15°C. To prevent antifreeze from freezing, add some water, because water is antifreeze for antifreeze.

OK, I had some fun... Seriously, here a typical diagram of the freezing point of an water-antifreeze mixture. It clearly shows that the best effect is achieved at about 60% antifreeze in water:

[image]

### Corrosion inhibitor

You could think that 25% antifreeze would be fine for your climate conditions. But antifreeze also inhibits corrosion inside your motor. Therefore, you need at least 50%.

### Heat capacity

The term *heat capacity* describes how much the temperature increases when you add some heat energy.

For water, it is 4.2J/(K * g) This means, to heat 1 gram of water by 1 K (same as 1°C), you need 4.2 Joule.
Other liquids are somewhere in the range of 1-2J/(K * g).

This makes water a superior coolant liquid, but with pure antifreeze, your car could overheat in the summer. Again, the less antifreeze, the better.

### Viscosity

Antifreeze has a low viscosity (i.e. how easy it flows. Honey has an extremely low viscosity). 
This will lead to a lower flow and so less effective cooling. I'm not sure how big this effect is, but at least, it will have a small effect on fuel consumption.

---

Finally, most points say that more water is better, but the corrosion part dictates that you should at least have 50% antifreeze, though you don't need the deep freezing point.

Too much coolant also has some adverse effects, so you shouldn't use pure antifreeze, too.

Stay with 50%, it's also cheaper.